# Checkbox text not visible

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked for possible roots of my issue but have been unable to do so.

I have some java Script that dynamically creates a list of check boxes. Some have text other have anchor links with text inside that.

It looks like this:

```
 createCheckbox: function (checkBoxDiv, sensorName, sensorId, checked, makeHyperLink, guid) {
        var liElement = document.createElement("li");
        var checkBoxElement = document.createElement("input");
        checkBoxElement.setType = "checkbox";
        checkBoxElement.name = "sensorName";
        checkBoxElement.id = "check" + sensorId;
        checkBoxElement.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkBoxElement.setAttribute("runat", "server");
        checkBoxElement.setAttribute("onchange", "OnCheckedChangedMethod('" + sensorName + "')");
        if (checked)
            checkBoxElement.setAttribute("checked", "true");
        if (makeHyperLink) {
            var linkElement = document.createElement("a");
            linkElement.setAttribute("style", "color:white;");
            linkElement.setAttribute("href", "#");
            linkElement.id = "link" + sensorId;
            linkElement.text = "" + sensorName;
            checkBoxElement.appendChild(linkElement);
        } else {
            checkBoxElement.setAttribute("text", sensorName);
        }
        liElement.appendChild(checkBoxElement);
        this.checkboxes++;
        return liElement;
}
```

This returns the element to be appended to my `div`.

It creates this list correctly and the `HTML` looks like this:

```
<ol id="sensorList"><li>
      Sensors
    </li><li><input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="sensorName" runat="server" onchange="OnCheckedChangedMethod('0-Predator Simulator (FLIR)')" checked="true"><a id="link1" style="color:white;" href="#">
      Item1
    </a></input></li><li><input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="sensorName" runat="server" onchange="OnCheckedChangedMethod('a')"><a id="link2" style="color:white;" href="#">
      Item2
    </a></input></li>
</ol>
```

The webpage looks like this:

[image]

I have tried removing all of my css incase it was something to do with that and nesting the text in other tags: `<p>` , `<h1>`but nothing changes.

Any thoughts on what the root of this problem might be. I am still fairly new to web programming.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a JSFiddle to demonstrate? Also why are you putting runat=server in there?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4estP/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input` element can't have children. So this:

```
checkBoxElement.appendChild(linkElement);
```

is incorrect.
Instead use label element that contains both checkbox and link:

```
var labelElement = document.createElement("label");
labelElement.appendChild(checkBoxElement);
labelElement.appendChild(linkElement);
```

Edit:
You can't click on link element to change checked state of the checkbox. because it refreshes the page (with `href='#'`). What do you want to do with link element?

Comment: Nice catch, the (to me) horrible way of writing that html stopped me seeing the nesting within the `input`

Comment: I am using delegate to assign a funtion to the click event of the llinks

Comment: Thank you, was unaware that you cannot have a child of an input, why is this "[a] horrible way of writing that html"? @DavidThomas So i can improve it.

Comment: Use jQuery and save your life.

Comment: @Zeb: well, this is how I'd have formatted it [JS Fiddle repro](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NSKPw/). (Though bear in mind it's *still* invalid HTML, so this is how it *should* look: [JS Fiddle repro](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NSKPw/1/)(though the `label` can either precede, or follow, according to your own taste/use-case).)